# Problem with my Advent of code day 1 part two code, no error message and no output

Tags: python

`/textdocument` stores 1000 strings (about 20 characters each) of random numbers and digits. The point of the program is to detect the first and last number (spelled out like `one` or as a digit `1`) and combine the into one digit (Ex: if at start of string there is `one` and last digit in string is `6` they will make `16`), then the program sums all of these two digit numbers into one big number (should be around 50,000).

I think my code looks good but i am getting no output or error message from my debug console or terminal. Could someone help me, I know it is a vague problem with probably an easy answer but i just cannot find it. the code is below:

```
with open('textdocument.txt', 'r') as f:
    line_list = f.readlines()
    
x = 0
calc = str(0)
sum = 0

def numConcat(num1, num2):
    return int("{}{}".format(num1, num2))
def my_reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]
def isnumberspelled(input):
    while True:
        if input.startswith("one") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "1") == True:
            return(1)
        elif input.startswith("two") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "2") == True:
            return(2)
        elif input.startswith("three") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "3") == True:
            return(3)
        elif input.startswith("four") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "4") == True:
            return(4)
        elif input.startswith("five") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "5") == True:
            return(5)
        elif input.startswith("six") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "6") == True:
            return(6)
        elif input.startswith("seven") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "7") == True:
            return(7)
        elif input.startswith("eight") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "8") == True:
            return(8)
        elif input.startswith("nine") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "9") == True:
            return(9)
        elif input.startswith("zero") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "0") == True:
            return(0)
        else:
            input = input[1:]

def isnumberspelledbackwards(input):
    while True:
        if input.endswith("one") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "1") == True:
            return(1)
        elif input.endswith("two") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "2") == True:
            return(2)
        elif input.endswith("three") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "3") == True:
            return(3)
        elif input.endswith("four") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "4") == True:
            return(4)
        elif input.endswith("five") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "5") == True:
            return(5)
        elif input.endswith("six") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "6") == True:
            return(6)
        elif input.endswith("seven") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "7") == True:
            return(7)
        elif input.endswith("eight") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "8") == True:
            return(8)
        elif input.endswith("nine") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "9") == True:
            return(9)
        elif input.endswith("zero") or (input[0:1].isdigit and input[0:1] == "0") == True:
            return(0)
        else:
            input = input[:-1]
        
def calculate(thing):
    return int(numConcat(isnumberspelled(thing), isnumberspelledbackwards(thing)))

while x < len(line_list):
    calc = str(line_list[x])
    sum = sum + calculate(calc)
    x = x + 1
print(sum)
```

I tried just about everything i know i am new to python: I tried my best to mess around with the class of numeric outputs. I made the output of calculate always be an int, idk if that is problematic.

Comment: You're missing the `()` to call the function in `input[0:1].isdigit`.

Comment: There's no reason to use a slice there, it should be `input[0].isdigit()`.

Comment: You don't even need to call `isdigit()`. You don't have to check if it's a digit before comparing with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `isdigit()` method because you left out the `()`. So you're just testing the method object itself, and this is always truthy.

You can simplify the code by realizing that if the character is a digit, `int()` will convert it to a number, you don't need to test separately for each digit. And for the number words, you can use a loop rather than lots of separate tests.

You should avoid using the names of Python built-in functions as variables, so I've renamed `input` to `string` below.

```
def isnumberspelled(string):
    number_strings = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
    while string:
        if string[0].isdigit():
            return int(string[0])

        for i, num in enumerate(number_strings):
            if string.startswith(num):
                return i

        string = string[1:]
```